# How can we define the communication line with the Ethereum Blockchain?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, ethereumjs

Imagine we have a wordpress website and you want to use the functionalities of the smart contract to test your business logic. I am using a web3 library with drupal to test my smart contract using Metamask & TestRPC locally.
is there a way to use wordpress/Drupal/Joomla to make a Dapp out of it? I want to know if  there is other ways to test a dapp without testRPC or Metamask or Mist, just with any browser?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you asking about alternative testing tools or how to get rid of Metamask/Mist and use a normal browser?

Comment: Yes kind of, how to use a normal browser without Mist or Metamask and still be able  to connect to the blockchain?

Comment: it's impossible if you want to keep a decentralised architecture (user manage his own account) . to avoid using these tools (mist, metamask..) you can use a remote node which would manage the user account, sign the transactions and broadcast the transactions (like the exchange markets do for exp).